# Placing a Custom View Inside Of A RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, charts

I want to embed a bar graph (from https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) into a view on my main activity screen. It works fine opening up by itself using `setContentView(barchart);`, but shows up super compacted into a corner (see last image) when I try to put it into a RelativeLayout (using `rl.addView(barchart);`).

**MainActivity.java**

```
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));

    BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("First");
    labels.add("Second");
    labels.add("Third");

    BarChart barchart = new BarChart(this);        //'this' for context seems to work
    //setContentView(barchart);

    BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
    barchart.setData(data);

    barchart.setNoDataTextDescription("Some bars should be here");
    barchart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    barchart.setDrawBorders(false);
    barchart.animateY(2000);





    //The RelativeLayout Approach

    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    rl.addView(barchart); // add the programmatically created chart
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#55656C"));


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    barchart.invalidate(); //Refresh chart, just in case
```

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutLabels"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### **Output**

**Works fine by itself!**

[image]

**Using the RelativeLayout approach:**

[image]

---

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Lol set your content view on the relativelayout approach.... setContentView(R.layout.idontknowthenameofyourlayoutxml);

Comment: @Sheychan was so funny huh? :-)

Comment: Oh I did'nt mean to laugh badly.. It's just an intro to a comment.. Anyways, I just wanna help you ;)

Comment: Did you try adding setContentView(R.layout.thexml); before declaring the Barchart then rl.addView(barchart);

Comment: I did. I added a third image showing the result of adding `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); ` in the 'RelativeLayout' section _after_  `rl.addView(barchart)`. I get the same output (jumbled text on a blue background) when I add the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);` _after_ the addView. I also updated the filenames in the headers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the bar chart from the xml the width/height is set to match parent and it is possible that setContentView is either using them or forcing match_parent anyway since it is about setting an activity content.

When you add it from the code with addView, you don't specify any layout parameters, and the default is wrap_content. Try changing your code using the lines below to see if it makes any difference:

```
rl.addView(
        barchart,
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```